# Dynamically building JavaScript by calling php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a general JavaScript that I want to use on multiple client websites. The JavaScript, among other things, will setup some event handlers. However, different clients may need different event handlers built, but every other part of the JavaScript will be the same. What I am looking into doing is writing a script tag:

```
<script src="myScript.php?client=clientName"></script>
```

And output a full JavaScript source with dynamically created event handlers and such.

I found this tutorial: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml about how to do this. But then I see things like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript which basically state this is a bad practice. So this brings me to my question: is this bad practice, or is that Stack Exchange question maybe a bit out of date?

From my understanding, as long as I am not executing anything that comes in through the query, but instead run it through a conditional statement, then there shouldn't be any risk really.

**EDIT:** If this is just a horrible practice then how might be a better way of doing this? Should I create a new JS file for each client? This seems tedious unless I create a server side program that generates a clients JS file as part of onboarding, but then it seems I might as well build it dynamically on the fly.

Comment: The argument on that page still stands: it’s somewhat of an antipattern. php is server, javascript is client. Writing your javascript in php will likely become unreadable and unmaintainable in the long run. It’s just confusing, even if it works...

Comment: Not to be stubborn, but then to understand correctly. It's about readability and clarity, not about safety and security?

Comment: But those are connected, because in a non-standard workflow you suddenly have to keep track of new possible pitfalls and points of failure in your app. The real question is, why do you even need it? Writing event listeners in php probably adds more problems than it solves.

Comment: This is fair. I actually found a way around it. I was just looking into this because it was going to make my life easier in the moment. But as with most things coding related, that doesn't always make it the best option it seems. I decided to design a system of arrays past from the server that would allow a JS loop to process them dynamically. Thanks for the input!